# What is the right word to describe something more than "great"

Tags: word-request, adjectives, synonyms, superlatives

I need to write short email that will state something like:

> ..that will turn a good company into a ... company.

What would be a proper word that I can use?

Comment: ".. into a [supercalifragilisticexpialidocious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) company"

Comment: You might want to focus on the qualities of a company this would improve, instead of just declaring that it would be better. For instance, 'a more successful company' or 'a more profitable company' Or '...that would make it a better place to work'.

Comment: An idiom for describing an increase in quality is "taking _x_ to the next level"; e.g "Increasing our user base is key to taking our business _to the next level_."

Comment: [_Fantastic!_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hs5zvzTcqrE)

Comment: if you are allowed to be informal maybe epic is a good choice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hrm, just a few observations on some of the answers here, from an American English speaker:

Many English versions of the word you're looking for were historically used to refer to things that are large in size, and can sometimes cause confusion on whether it's exceptionally good, or exceptionally large.  In context the difference is often clear, but when describing a company (which could be made larger) the meaning may not be so clear.  Be careful when using words like "tremendous" or even "great" / "grand".

Similarly, many English words come from descriptions of things that are so exceptional that they are better than real life.  "Fantastic" can frequently be used to describe something that has an element of fantasy, which it's unlikely that your company would have.  "Legendary" and "epic" can suffer from the same.  Additionally, due to its (over)use in modern informal speech I think "epic" has lost much of its weight and may also appear informal, as user13267 mentioned.

"Marvelous" and "phenomenal" aren't bad suggestions at all, but CAN have an air of supernatural greatness (i.e. more "great" than something can ever be in real life) similar to the previous bunch.  Personally, I think these would probably work in the given context.

"Exemplary" isn't bad, but may sometimes imply something that sets an example for others to follow.  This might fit your case, however.

I like Thomas Mario Adams III's suggestion of "outstanding", particularly because this company would literally "stand out" from among other merely "great" companies.  It's also term that is very familiar to corporate readers.  You may want to add emphasis by saying the company will become "truly outstanding".

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Good observations of other aspects. Also: excellent (highly performing), wonderful/awesome (full of wonder/awe), magnificent (majestic, worthy of a ruler)...  there are numerous positive words, but a common issue is having sort of extra little meaning attached to them.  Even terrific looks like the word "terrifyingly".  So there might be some cases where the word isn't quite the perfect match, whereas "great" is more universal (mostly meaning "good" although there is a smaller implication of being "large", using "great" to mean "good" about something "small" would typically seem just fine).

Answer (score 16):

Consider [excellent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excellent)

> very good of its kind, eminently good

or [outstanding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outstanding).

> extremely good or excellent

<sub>note that these words start with vowels, so the 'a' turns into 'an'</sub>

Comment: If we're talking about a company, I would definitely go with "outstanding".

Answer (score 8):

You may consider

> Exceptional

From the [online dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exceptional), definition 2:

> unusually excellent; superior:
>   an exceptional violinist.

Answer (score 4):

Phenomenal

**adjective**

> highly extraordinary or prodigious; exceptional:

[Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/phenomenal)

> astounding, exceptional

[Source](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/phenomenal)

Usage example:

...will turn a good company into a phenomenal success!

Answer (score 2):

Consider

an **exemplary** company

as a way to express that this company will be turned into "something more than great"

Answer (score 1):

Think of *marvelous, fantastic, the best*. *The best* is fine.

Comment: These are legitimate words, but I don't think you'll find _marvelous_ or _fantastic_ used to describe a corporation all that often. (There are [a few](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=excellent+company%2Coutstanding+company%2Cfantastic+company%2Cmarvelous+company&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), but not many.) These suggestions wouldn't be among my primary choices.

Comment: 'Marvelous company' might also refer to a group of people.  That Google Ngram won't show how big a percentage refers to 'companies' in the sense of 'business entities'.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the others I would like to add

> Superb, Epic, Legendary

[This answer over on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/299012/37082) has a good amount of information on intensifiers like this that is worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Many companies today are referred to as "great" companies. But great has become cliche. What I'm saying is even better than great, it's an "outstanding" company. An outlier to the great ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the word `remarkable`

[Remarkable:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/remarkable)
1.
notably or conspicuously unusual; extraordinary:
a remarkable change.
2.
worthy of notice or attention.